# Flutter Error : No Firebase App ‘[DEFAULT]’ has been created – call Firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: flutter

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firestore.initializeApp();
  runApp(BookApp());
}
```

I used these codes but firestore is not recognized in main.dart
I am using latest versions

```
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the following, if you have missed some steps:

Create a firebase project in the firebase console.

Make sure the bundleID of the app matches with the bundle ID of the project created in Console.

Android: Make sure you have copied the google-services.json file to the Android>app directory (copy item if needed)

iOS: Make sure you have copied the GoogleServices-Info.plist file to iOS>Runner directory.

try flutter clean and restart the app

Answer (score 1):

You need to intialize [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire) first by calling `await Firebase.initializeApp();` before using any Firebase services.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await Firestore.initializeApp();
  runApp(BookApp()
}
```